# Android Google API Speech recognition

Tags: android, api, voice, speech

i would create an app which uses speech recognition, but i'm new in this kind of implementation and i would know if you can help me. I've looked for here

```
http://developer.android.com/
```

i didn't find anything about it.

I would know how to use Google API speech recognition..can you suggest me some link please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This book:
[http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Android-Sensor-Programming-Milette/dp/1118183487/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118183487)

Check out the code here: https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib

specifically: This class: https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib/blob/master/library/src/root/gast/speech/SpeechRecognizingActivity.java

Just have your code extend SpeechRecognizingActivity and you can be started in no time.

Comment: Does this works for english language only or  for other languages too? I'm interested to italian language